Is it possible to share the audio input to a remote connection?
When working from home I use a Windows 10 laptop. I use the Microsoft store application Remote Desktop to remote into my office Windows 11 machine.
If I'm in a Microsoft Teams or Zoom call, on can hear everything in the online meeting app fine. But neither MS Teams of Zoom will "hear" me when I use my headset which I connect to my laptop via a USB port.
So, I've resorted to calling in to either the MS Teams or Zoom call with my phone. That has worked OK, until last night when the online meeting went longer than 3 hours, my earbuds died.
I'm wondering is there a way I can use my headset connected to the laptop with the USB cable?

This question was addressed on Super User as a comment, quoting Microsoft: "Bi-directional sound can be configured in the Windows client on a per-connection basis. The relevant settings can be accessed in the Remote audio section of the Local Resources options tab."

Apparently, assuming the machine at work is the client, then your workplace must enable sound for your connection.
Please test and let me know if that works. Thanks.

Thank you! I'm going to give this a try.
